# Как правильно организовать заполнение таблицы sql?

Tags: sql, sqlite

У меня создано 3 таблицы. Я прочитал, что связь лучше всего устанавливать по id, в третьей таблице у меня именно так и сделано. Но сами данные для ввода (в 3 таблицу) у меня хранятся в типе TEXT а не в INTEGER, т.е. они введены в CurrencyCode.Code и в CurrencyName.Name.
Вопрос заключается в том, правильно ли я рассуждаю: для заполнения Currency.id_CodeExecute и Currency.id_NameExecute придется получать id, и делать это путем сравнения вводимого текста c CurrencyCode.Code и CurrencyName.Name?
Если я правильно понимаю, покажите пожалуйста пример подобного запроса на SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE "CurrencyCode" (
"id_Code"   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"Code"  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE );

CREATE TABLE "CurrencyName" (
"id_Name"   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"Name"  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);

CREATE TABLE "Currency" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "id_CodeExecute"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "id_NameExecute"    INTEGER NOT NULL,       
    FOREIGN KEY("id_CodeExecute") REFERENCES "CurrencyCode"("id_Code"),
    FOREIGN KEY("id_NameExecute") REFERENCES "CurrencyName"("id_Name"),
    PRIMARY KEY("id","id_CodeExecute","id_NameExecute")
);
```

Comment: Не понял... одному Code могут соответствовать несколько Name? И наоборот?

Comment: @Akina да, верно.

Comment: Ну так какие проблемы? `insert into t1 (t2_id, t3_id, field) select t2.id, t3.id, 'literal' from t2, t3 where t2.txt='text2' and t3.txt='text3'`. Поскольку textX в каждой таблице уникален, в итоге вставляется одна запись.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо за помощь, я так примерно и представлял себе, просто не было уверенности что это верный подход в целом. Вообще если честно сомневаюсь стоит ли в данном случае использовать в качестве первичных ключей INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, т.к. Code и Name у меня уникальны всегда и без повторов, и без изменений...

Comment: ПК-текст, тем более FK - совсем не лучшая идея.. особенно если речь идёт о хоть чуть-чуть приличном по объёму массиве данных.